# Hide/Unhide IBOutlet(UIButton) when a IAP is complete

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Alright, so I've been toying around with this for a couple days now and I haven't gotten this to work, looking to you for help!
Basically I want to "Unlock" a feature once an IAP is done. I've got the IAP code to work, but I want to change the button "sendMail" ('disabled' in Interface Builder) so that the user can interact with it.

```
//InputViewController.h
#import "IAPStore.h"
@interface InputViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIButton *sendMail;
-(void)enableMail;
....
@end

//InputViewController.m
#import "InputViewController.h"
#import "IAPStore.h"
-(void)enableMail
{
  [_sendMail setEnabled:YES];
  NSLog(@"Unlocking Button");
}

//IAPStore.h
#import "InputViewController.h"
@interface IAPHelper : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>
-(void)purchaseComplete;
...
@end

//IAPStore.m
#import "InputViewController.h"
-(void)purchaseComplete
{
   UIAlertView *purchased = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"In-App Purchase"   message:@"Purchase complete! Thank you!" delegate:nil
   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
   GROWInputViewController *viewController = [[GROWInputViewController alloc] init];
   [viewController enableMail];
   [purchased show];
   NSLog(@"button enabled");
}
```

So it prints out too the log but nothing is changed on the other view controller, but nothing is changed, any idea to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You allocate a view controller and then throw it away. You need to access the property on the instance of the view controller that has its view visible already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `NSNotificationCenter`

In the `viewDidLoad:` method of InputViewController.m add this line of code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(enableMail) name:@"purchaseCompleteNotification" object:nil];
```

And in the `purchaseComplete` method of IAPStore.m, replace this:

```
GROWInputViewController *viewController = [[GROWInputViewController alloc] init];
[viewController enableMail];
```

with this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"purchaseCompleteNotification" object:nil];
```

This will cause a notification to be posted when the purchase is complete. Meanwhile, `InputViewController` has an 'observer' that is set to call your 'enableMail' method when that notification is posted.

Also, you'll want to add this method to your InputViewController.m, so that he is removed as an observer when deallocated.

```
-(void)dealloc{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"purchaseCompleteNotification" object:nil];
}
```

Comment: @ieatsubway - Welcome. Also it's good practice to localize that notification name into a static string variable somewhere. To avoid typos and such.